# Seed data to PSQL with Sequelize has different IDs every time seed script runs

Tags: sequelize.js, psql, seeding

I have a seedDB script to seed data into my PSQL database. The data comes in fine for the most part, but the IDs for the Genre table and are different every time I run my seed:db script. The artist table is in the same order as the array in my data, but the rest of the tables are seeded in a jumbled order every time. This is a problem because I make associations based on IDs so these associations are different every time I run the file. How can I seed my database so that the IDs are the same every time and I can make the correct associations?

models/index.js

```
require('dotenv').config();

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const db = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DATABASE_URL,
{
    underscored: true,
    returning: true,
  },
);

const Artist = db.define('artist', {
  name: {
    type:      Sequelize.STRING(128),
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
  desc: {
    type:       Sequelize.TEXT,
    allowNull:  false,
  },
  img_url: {
    type:       Sequelize.TEXT,
    allowNull:  false,
  },
});

const Genre = db.define('genre', {
  name: {
    type:      Sequelize.STRING(64),
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
});

const Album = db.define('album', {
  name: {
    type:      Sequelize.STRING(128),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  img_url: {
    type:       Sequelize.TEXT,
    allowNull:  false,
  },
});

const Show = db.define('show', {
  date: {
    type:     Sequelize.DATEONLY,
    allowNull:  false,
  },
  venue: {
    type:      Sequelize.STRING(64),
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

//associations
Show.belongsToMany(Artist, { through: 'artist_show_xref'});
Artist.belongsToMany(Show, { through: 'artist_show_xref'});

Genre.belongsToMany(Artist, { through: 'artist_genre_xref'});
Artist.belongsToMany(Genre, { through: 'artist_genre_xref'});

Artist.hasMany(Album);
Album.belongsTo(Artist);

module.exports = {
    Artist, 
    Genre, 
    Album, 
    Show, 
    db,
};
```

data/index.js

```
module.exports = {
//name, desc, img_url, [genre1,genre2,genre3]
  artists: [
    ['Jachary', 'Originally from Boston, 25-year-old Jachary is now based in Bushwick, New York. On his debut album, "There\'s A Virus Going On" he plays most of the instruments, produces, and does vocals on each track. His versatility when it comes to every aspect of creating music allowshim to craft a unique sound that blends elements from funk, rock, and hip hop.','http://www.allthingsgomusic.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Jachary-1.jpg',["Funk","Jazz"]],
    ['Jazze Belle', 'Jazze Belle is a duo comprised of producer/instrumentalist Jett and singer/songwriter Taylor Simone. Both hail from different parts of the country (Taylor\'s from LA and Jett\'s from Richmond), but the two share a sound influenced by jazzy vocals, soulful chords, and hip hop digital production. Playing everywhere in NYC from Nola, Darling to Baby\'s All Right, they are equipped with a musical tenacity and talent to match.','https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/837340614765207552/wEDG12iC_400x400.jpg',["Experimental","Jazz"]],
    ['Jelani Sei', 'One of the few bands in the northeast that can lull you with ethereal soundscapes while simultaneously sending you into a a crazy mosh, Jelani Sei is a group of individuals who are constantly searching the realms of harmony to find that new groove. Jelani Sei represents not only unity, but love, passion and a drive to push oneself beyond limits they didn\'t think they were capable of.','https://f4.bcbits.com/img/0011355358_10.jpg',["Soul","Funk"]],
    ['L\'Rain', 'Lead by composer and multi-instrumentalist Taja Cheek, L\'Rain puts on a special performance as a quartet. Hailed by the New York Times as a \'one-woman studio band\' L\'Rain puts on one of the best experimental live shows in the whole city','https://www.tinymixtapes.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/Article_Width/1707/dsc_1619-2.jpg',["Jazz","Alt-rock"]],
    ['Space Captain', 'Space Captain is a Brooklyn based psych-soul group signed to UK indie label Tru Thoughts.In a period of open-minded experimentation via live shows and studio jams, Space Captain have alighted on a progressive fusion of R&B and psychedelic rock with tentacles spinning out into soul, hip hop, electronica and noise.','http://nyc.thedelimagazine.com/sites/upload-files/20292747_1921203848119544_6591279462890360259_n.jpg',["Alt-rock"]],
    ['Star the Moonlight','Star the Moonlight is a neo-soul band straight from the outer rim, brimming with lush timbres and harmonies and driven by the powerful rhythmic interplay of interlocking grooves. Inspiration is taken from Richard Strauss, Frank Zappa and Dirty Projectors to create a mind melding mix of synthetic and acoustic textures, like a Van Gogh reimagined','https://scontent-lga3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/15167686_1340660815979083_340349751037127786_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&_nc_eui2=AeF0q35rPri5id6u4fo1Y_Fc59kJHrsCdRXXm-vXfbEUeqY79l5CkO70LTp4UVMxoPq7ESYShH5HjY5zQD3N5MErMysecAlCCdWlgTLkGJkJdw&oh=cec12280fd397db14e9b968b8e467ccc&oe=5BE6F690',["Jazz","Alt-rock"]],
    ['Valipala','Based in NYC since 2012, Valipala (formerly known as With Snack) tips their hats to the great groove makers of yesteryear while continuing to rethink modern R&B with a union of funk, jazz, and progressive rock. Known for their virtuosic arrangements and animated live shows, a night with Valipala is bound to somehow leave you both exhausted and energized.','https://d3jjg4nf4bbybe.cloudfront.net/u/300963/4f1ab18853472ef82ec986b1ea5ceffcf2989979/original/valipalamayshoot5.jpg/!!/b:W1sicmVzaXplIiw2NzBdLFsibWF4Il0sWyJ3ZSJdXQ==.jpg',["Soul","Funk"]],
    ['Vinegar Mother','Vinegar Mother is carving  its own niche up and down the East Coast\'s live music circuit. The psychedelic soul-rock  quintet has attracted fans from Brooklyn to Burlington, and  everywhere  in  between.','https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.imposemagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Vinegar-Mother-Hi-Res-1024x683.jpg',["Funk","Jazz","Soul"]],
    ['Woolly Mammals','Woolly Mammals is an alternative-soul quartet from Brooklyn, New York. Since their debut release, \'Cheap Talk\' in January 2017 the band has received praise from Rolling Stone France, No Treble Magazine, Live for Live Music, and Nextbop. With the recent release of their debut EP, When You Get This, in January 2018, the band continues to deliver their own haughtily original brand of techno-funk, layering a talking bass vocoder on top ofsoaring synthesizers, swampy subs, and acid-jazz backbeats.','https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DJSyIcWXkAAO98R.jpg',["Jazz"]],
    ['Panther Hollow','Led by singer-songwriter Bernardo Ochoa, Panther Hollow combines elements of grunge, indie rock and folk.',"https://f4.bcbits.com/img/0009339227_10.jpg",["Indie-rock","Folk","Punk"]],  
    ['Renata Zeiguer', 'Renata Zeiguer is a Brooklyn-based multi-instrumentalist singer-songwriter, the daughter of Argentinean and Philippine immigrants. An NYC native, she grew up playing classical and jazz music, beginning on the violin and the piano at age 6, and listening to her grandmother play ragtime and tango music obsessively on a baby grand during family visits in Buenos Aires.', 'https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58b8a99fd1758e4cc2690804/t/5b56279c352f536f231f175d/1532372903944/Renata+Zeiguer-5941.jpg',['Alt-rock','Indie-rock']],  
    ['Madison McFerrin','Brooklyn-based singer/songwriter, Madison McFerrin, is described by the New York Times as "show[ing] wonderful vocal dexterity, deftly swerving from sharp, clearly enunciated staccato bursts to fluttery, free-form melismata.','https://assets.rbl.ms/18274061/980x.jpg',['Soul','R&B']]
  ],
  //genre name
  genres: [
  ['Funk'],
  ['Jazz'],
  ['Soul'],
  ['Alt-rock'],
  ['Experimental'],
  ['Hip-hop'],
  ['Indie-rock'],
  ['Electronic'],
  ['Psychedelic'],
  ['R&B'],
  ['Punk'],
  ],

  //name,img_url,artist
  albums:[
    ['Mango City', 'https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a3147368541_10.jpg',7],
    ['All Flowers In Time', 'https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a0708663422_10.jpg',5],
    ['There\'s a Virus Going On','https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a0703511586_10.jpg',1],
    ['Go To Bed Standing Up','https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000209628840-dh3giq-t500x500.jpg',2],
    ['LVNDR TWN', 'https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a0918581716_10.jpg', 3],
    ['L\'Rain','https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a0453705262_16.jpg', 4],
    ['Haven\'t You Heard', 'https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a2742014305_16.jpg', 6],
    ['Phases','https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a0762015821_16.jpg',8],
    ['When You Get This', 'https://millsrecordcompany.com/Photo/418458928650:500', 9],
    ['People Synestesia','https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a1114866823_10.jpg',10],
    ['Old Ghost','https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a0430570891_16.jpg',11],
    ],
//date, venue, [artists in show]
  shows:[
   ['2018-10-26', 'Coney Island Baby', [1,3]],
   ['2018-11-06', 'C\'mon Everybody', [5]],
   ['2018-11-08', 'Pianos', [2,6,7]],
   ['2018-11-08', 'Mercury Lounge', [9,11]],
  ]
}
```

seedDB

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const { Artist, Genre, Album, Show, db } = require('../models');
const { artists, genres, albums, shows } = require('../data');


(async () => {
  await Promise.all(artists.map(async ([name, desc, img_url, genres]) => {
    try {
      const newArtist = await Artist.create({ name, desc, img_url });
      const newGenres = await Promise.all(genres.map(name =>
        Genre.findOrCreate({ where: { name } }).then(([g]) => g)));
      return newArtist.setGenres(newGenres);
    } catch (e) {
      throw (e.message);
    }
  }));

  await Promise.all([
    Album.bulkCreate(albums.map(([name, img_url, artist_name]) => ({ name, img_url, artist_name }))),
    Promise.all(shows.map(async ([date, venue, artists]) => {
      const newShow = await Show.create({ date, venue });
      return newShow.setArtists(artists);
    })),
  ]);     
  db.close();
})();
```

And here's one example of how the Genre table seeds in Postico

[postico seeding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er04v.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I is that you are depending upon Sequelize 
to insert a primary key and generate default ids for you which is fine but if you do it that way, you need nested inserts. For seed data like Country, State tables, it’s easier to use pre generated keys and insert with the data.

Comment: Hi Brian, just noticed my inbox now, thanks for the response. I tried creating my own primary keys in my models and I ran into the same issue. But isn't my seed file as posted above already a nested insert? I'm creating the artists, then the genres, then setting the genres to the artists.